# Oracle bulkcopy date format issue

Tags: .net, oracle, date, csv, datatable

This is exactly my issue but couoldn't find a suitable answer so asking again...
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/775780/Year-and-century-being-swapped-when-inserting-a-da

I am importing data from csv to oracle db. Csv to datatable and to db using oracle bulkcopy. The date format in datatble is ddMONyy (05FEB15). But in database  it is saved as dd-MON-yy (05-FEB-20). Select statement gives 02/05/1520. 
The millennium part of the year and the year are swapped. Why does this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it not possible to get the dates passed across in the csv file as four digit years? It's like y2k never even happened.

Comment: date in csv file 2/5/2015(edit mode) and displayed as 5-Feb-15... But if I change the date column datatype to varchar2, then I am able to save the date as 02/05/2015. I couldn't understand the reason for this "swap" behavior in the date datatype.

Comment: Where are you viewing the csv file, and what is being passed into the OracleBulkCopy? I'm wondering if Excel is rearing its ugly head here, and that's maybe throwing a spanner in the works.

Comment: I am viewing the CSV file in excel. I am copying the csv data to datable and then passing the datatable to oracleBulkCopy.

Comment: I tried all of the date format combinations, yet to resolve this error. But meanwhile I did a dirty work, converted the date column to varchar2. I format the date string using this line "Date.ParseExact(fieldData(18), "d-MMM-yy", Nothing).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")" where field(18) is a csv reader value and save it to db. In select quesry, I use to_date(). Anyhow, I still couldn't figure the "swap" issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the reason for 1520 swap. As mentioned in the comments above,  I changed the date column to varchar2 in the database and I was able to load:

```
 row("EXPORT_DATE") = fieldData(19)
                '****************************Check for the date formats to avoid error when exporting****************************
                Dim formats = New String() {"dd-MMM-yyyy", "d-MMM-yyyy", "dd-MMM-yy", "d-MMM-yy", "ddMMMyyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "M/d/yyyy"}
                Dim outDate As Date
                If (Date.TryParseExact(fieldData(19), formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, outDate)) Then
                    row("EXPORT_DATE") = outDate.ToString("ddMMMyyyy")
                    'Else 'Not working
                    '    row("EXPORT_DATE") = outDate.ToString("ddMMMyyyy")
                End If
                '****************************Check for the date formats to avoid error when exporting****************************
```